# What is this large insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

A large (body about 4 cm long) flying insect flew into my workshed when it was very dark, warm and humid outside, probably attracted by the lights. It fell onto the bench upside down and could not turn back onto its legs. Video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQdFE4P-HHo

[image]

Can someone please identify the species? This is the very bottom of New Zealand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a full answer we would need to have further pictures of the back of the insect. However, NZ has few insects of that size range that are at all common, so I suspect that what you have here is a [Huhu beetle](https://www.landcareresearch.co.nz/tools-and-resources/identification/what-is-this-bug/huhu-beetle/) (*Prionoplus reticularis*).

The Huhu beetle is a widespread, large, brown beetle that is often in the 40-50 mm (~2 inch) range, with a pattern of reticulated veins on the elytra. They have brown hairs on the head and thorax and long antennae, that are often 1/3 or up to as long as the body. The species are largely known as a "wild food", with the grubs (larvae) eaten raw or fried. They are also fairly heavy fliers and make quite a racket flapping around. Completely harmless to people.

Edited to add: Having watched the video; a couple of seconds from the end you can see the elytra with the patterns on, so I am confident that this is a Huhu beetle.

The larvae are commonly found in rotting wood, particularly conifers (pine, macrocarpa), so if you have those around, that's where they will be coming from.